# Override ServiceHost class

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I run a Windows Service with a WCF service library and I need to override the `OnOpening()` to process some operation.

Here is my custom class who inherit from `ServiceHost` :

```
public class StratusServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        private Type type;

        public StratusServiceHost(Type t, Uri baseAddresses) :
            base(t, baseAddresses) { }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();
        }
    }
```

And here is my Host class used to instanciate my Windows Service :

```
internal class StratusHost
    {
        static StratusServiceHost serviceHost = null;
        public StratusHost()
        {

        }

        internal static void Start()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
                serviceHost.Close();
//serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StratusApiService));
            serviceHost = new StratusServiceHost(typeof(StratusApiService));
            serviceHost.Open();
        }

        internal static void Stop()
        {
            if (serviceHost != null)
            {
                serviceHost.Close();
                serviceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm unable to compile the solution and get the following error :

> StratusServiceHost.StratusServiceHost' does not contain a constructor
>   that takes 1 arguments

But if you take the documentation of `ServiceHost`, there is no constructor with one parameters and `serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StratusApiService))` still works.

`ServiceHost` constructors :

```
protected ServiceHost();
public ServiceHost(object singletonInstance, params Uri[] baseAddresses);
public ServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `params` keyword in your implementation on the constructor.  Try changing:

```
public StratusServiceHost(Type t, Uri baseAddresses) :
        base(t, baseAddresses) { }
```

To:

```
public StratusServiceHost(Type t, params Uri baseAddresses) :
        base(t, baseAddresses) { }
```

The [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword allows you to send a variable number of arguments - if none are supplied, it's treated as array with zero length.  Which is why this line works:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StratusApiService));
```

You're not really calling a one-argument constructor, your calling a constructor that takes 2 arguments.  You just don't have to supply anything for the second parameter in this case.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. I get the following error now : `The parameter array must be a single dimensional array`

Comment: @XavierW - The error seems pretty self-explanatory.   Can you post the actual line of code that is causing the error?